# Замена <center> на CSS

Tags: html, css, html5

Возникла проблема, хочу создать блок по центру с отступами от верха и низа, остановился на таком варианте, он вроде как рабочий:

```
    body{
        max-width: 500px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        color: #565665;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
    .addressform {
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
        height: 600px;
        width: 400px
    }

    <center>
        <div class="addressform">
            <form action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend align="left">Адрес отправления посылки</legend>
                    <table>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
```

Но я хочу заменить < center > на CSS. пробовал несколько вариантов, в том числе тоже самое только без < center >, но в таком случае, весь div смещается на влево на пикселей 20 и вся эта штука стоит уже не ровно по центру.

```
        <div class="addressform">
            <form action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend align="left">Адрес отправления посылки</legend>
                    <table>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: `.addressform { margin: auto; }` ?

Comment: Все заработало)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй технологию Flex Box.

```
<style>
body{
  margin:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.flex__box{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.addressform {
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
        height: 600px;
        width: 400px
    }
</style>

      <div class="flex__box">
        <div class="addressform">
            <form action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend align="left">Адрес отправления посылки</legend>
                    <table>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Пример есть здесь:
[Пример](https://jsgraph.kamakepar.repl.co/try.html)